# tf message type error

Tags: transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,All,

I have written some codes to subscribe the `/tf` topic as below:

```
void msgcbTf(const geometry_msgs::TransformStamped & msgTf){
    ROS_INFO("Sequence ID:[%d]",msgTf.header.seq);
    ROS_INFO("msg time:[%d,%d]",msgTf.header.stamp.sec,msgTf.header.stamp.nsec);
    ROS_INFO("tf[x=%f,y=%f]",msgTf.transform.translation.x,msgTf.transform.translation.y);
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    ros::init(argc,argv,"CyberMapInfo");
    ros::NodeHandle n; 

    ros::Subscriber subTf=n.subscribe("tf",40,msgcbTf);
    ROS_INFO("Substribe /tf.");
    ros::spin();
}
```

There was a fatal error when the node run and the callback function *msgcbTf* had not been called successfully:

`[ERROR] [1442566935.682455302]: Client [/CyberMapInfo] wants topic /tf to have datatype/md5sum [geometry_msgs/TransformStamped/b5764a33bfeb3588febc2682852579b0], but our version has [tf2_msgs/TFMessage/94810edda583a504dfda3829e70d7eec]. Dropping connection.`

So what message type should I use to take place of **geometry_msgs::TransformStamped** in *msgcbTf* function or how can I solve this problem by other way?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/217846/tf-message-type-error/) by [redskydeng](https://answers.ros.org/users/22936/redskydeng/) on ROS Answers with karma: 118 on 2015-09-18

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you're trying to subscribe to the `/tf` topic you need to use the other datatype mentioned in your error message `tf2_msgs/TFMessage`

You could find that out by using `rostopic info /tf`.

I suggest you work through some of the [core ROS tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials) which will help with your debugging.

It's also not recommended to subscribe to `/tf` directly but use a `TransformListener` as described in the [tf Tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Tutorials)

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2015-09-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [redskydeng](https://answers.ros.org/users/22936/redskydeng/) on 2015-09-20**:
Thanks a lot!